# Assign object by reference, without copying

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

The following fails as the object I want to assign is being *copied* over then *destroyed*. So should I be declaring `B::data` as a pointer instead, or is there some better fancy way to assign by reference rather than copying (I want to avoid triggering the dtor)?

```
class B {
    class myContainer{
        myContainer()  {/* allocate memory */}
        ~myContainer() {/* free memory */}
        ...
    };
    myContainer data;
};

...
void foo() {
    B x;
    x.data = myContainer(...);  // creates a myContainer, *copies* to x.data, then destroys 
}
```

Ideally I don't want to use `new` as I want to allocate myContainer on the stack (and hence not have to manually manage memory, which is the whole point of automatically freeing in the dtor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is to have `data` be a reference to `myContainer`. So:

```
class B
{
  public:
    class myContainer
    {
      ... 
    };
    myContainer& data;
    B(myContainer& d) : data(d) {} 
};

void foo()
{
    B::myContainer a;
    B x(a); 
}
```

Note: You will need `myContainer` to last at least as long as `B` does in this case, so there is a good argument for NOT doing things in this case if you can foresee someone doing this:

```
B* bar()
{
   B::myContainer a;
   B *p = new B(a);
   return p;
}
```

Now, when `bar` ends, `a` is being destroyed. But there is still a reference to it in `*p`, so things will go very weird when we try to use `p->data` in some way.

Comment: Apologies - I was being slightly lazy and imprecise with my example, `mycontainer` is actually a child class, as updated now.

Comment: Changes very little, except for how you have to type it (assuming it is `public`, otherwise it can't be used outside the class).

Comment: As it currently stands (in the original post) isn't `myContainer` simply an inner class lexically speaking? To be a child class you would need inheritance i.e. `class myContainer : public B`

Comment: Yes, an inner class is what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited in the required "B::" in relevant places (I think). As I said, it really doesn't alter the conceptual solution, just the details of what you have to type. Unless I've missed something.